# Why does the "size_of_array" template fucntion does not work with int a[n] (size defined at runtime) while it works fine with int a[4]?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, variable-length-array

```
template <typename T, int n >
int tell_me_size(T (&) [n]){
  return n;
}
```

this code works fine with

```
int a[4];
cout<< tell_me_size(a)<<endl;
```

while does not work with

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n];
cout<< tell_me_size(a)<<endl;
```

The later gives the error "no matching function for call to ‘tell_me_size(int [n])"

Comment: `int a[n]` where `n` is a runtime variable is not a valid c++

Comment: Templates are compile-time.

Comment: @JaneDoe doesn't apply here really.

Comment: `cin>>n; int a[n];` is not legal C++.  add the `-pedantic-errors` compiler flag and the code will no longer compile.

Comment: The big 3 compilers saying VLAs are non-standard - live - https://godbolt.org/z/E9saMrs9q

Comment: Legal, illegal, either way, the compiler can't instantiate a template around a value the user will provide in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ 20 Standard (13.4.3 Template non-type arguments)

> 2 A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be **a
> converted constant expression** (7.7) of the type of the
> template-parameter.

Pay attention to that variable length arrays like this

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n];
```

are not a standard C++ feature.